# Need guidance in non C/C++ based graphics interface

Tags: c++, graphics, widget

I have prepared a program launcher in C++ (the only language I know), which accepts strings as program trigger.
But however hard I try I'm unable to give it a GUI like look; using graphics.h's graph functions creates graphics but in cmd like window.

All I need is a small widget/window like thing that sits on the desktop where a user can type the command string (and error messages can be displayed as usual).

Can I get a code snippet for such a widget/window?
The input string may be copied to a .txt file and my prog will read it from there.

P.S.- I'm a beginner & rookie so please avoid complex alternatives.

Comment: Hi C tyson, try adding the tag C++ to your question, it might help it get more views and a higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I'm afraid as soon as you want to use a GUI you can't avoid complexity. The whole premise is reversed: instead of the program controlling the flow, the user controls the flow, and that requires a whole different way of operating.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the easiest options in my opinion is to use .NET Framework:

http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/04/my-first-windows-cplusplus-application-in-ages-hello-world-in-win32-with-visual-cplusplus-2010

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384845.aspx